# Remove the gap between span elements when using "transform: scale"

Tags: html, css, scale

I have a simple paragraph containing text where each letter is in a `<span>` so that I can put a background-color on each of them. Basically, this is needed to do text highlighting.

However, the content is scaled up using `transform: scale()` on the body, which makes gaps appear between each `<span>`.

An example : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XbQXBw
By changing the scale back to 1 or any other Integer value, there is no more gap. How to make it go away when scale is a Float value?

Comment: Why are you doing it this way? Why not just change the font-size?

Comment: i don't have a solution off the top of my head, but i can tell you why: it's just round-off causing a loss of precision in the rendering engine. the positioning can be done to sub-pixel accuracy, but the fill can only be done to the nearest pixel, so sometimes that leaves a one-pixel sliver. that sliver will also be different from browser to browser based on how it does the round-off.

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot adjust with font-size? Also, when using zero values use `0`, no need to define the unit. i.e do this: `padding: 0;` instead of `padding: 0px;`.

Comment: Why don't you use `<span style="background-color:rgb(183, 61, 61)">abcde</span>` ?

Comment: @la1ch3 because the whole content of the page is scale since I want it to fit every screen on every device, which is why I put the scale on the body and not the text itself

Comment: @Hearner because as I said in the post, this is to to text highlighting, so I want to be able to highlight one letter only and not the whole word

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow so basically I should log an issue with Chrome rather than here? :)

Comment: well, i don't think it's something they would consider a bug. if it were rounded off to your benefit in this use case, there would be other use cases in which the behavior would be undesired. you can try, though.